# Remove an item with a swipe from recyclerView and sqliteDb

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to remove an item from recyclerView and sqlite with a swipe. What should I pass to dbHelper?

I tried passing the id of the element using `mainAdapter.items [position]` but it throws `an Element index 8 must be in range [0..7] error` Even if you add one element to the newly installed application and try to delete it, it will throw `an Element index 8 must be in range [0..1] error`.

```
        val itemTouchHelperCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                    var item = mainAdapter.items[position]
                (mainAdapter as MainAdapter).removeItem(viewHolder,container.context)
                    var db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
                    Toast.makeText(context,"${item.id} + ${item.body} + ${item.title}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

Code of my dbHelper:

```
class dbHelper(context: Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION){
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val CREATE_TABLE_QUERY:String = ("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME ($KEY_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $KEY_TITLE TEXT, $KEY_BODY TEXT);")
        db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun addNote(note: Note){
        val db = writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(KEY_TITLE,note.title)
        values.put(KEY_BODY,note.body)

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values)
        db.close()
    }

    fun getAllNotes():MutableList<Note>{
        val noteList = ArrayList<Note>()
        val db = readableDatabase
        val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null)
        if(cursor!=null){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    val notes = Note()
                    notes.id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)))
                    notes.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE))
                    notes.body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_BODY))
                    noteList.add(notes)
                }while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
        }
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
        return noteList.toMutableList()
    }

    fun deleteItem(note: Note){
        val db = writableDatabase
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + "=?"+note.id, null)
    }

    fun deleteAll() {
        var db = writableDatabase
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null)
    }

    companion object{
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "note_database.db"
        private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        private val TABLE_NAME = "notes"
        private val KEY_ID = "id"
        private val KEY_TITLE = "title"
        private val KEY_BODY = "body"
    }
}
```

Code of my adapter:

```
class MainAdapter (var items: MutableList<Note>,val callback: Callback) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        MainHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_note,parent,false))

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }

    fun getItem(position: Int): Note{
        return items.get(position)
    }

    interface onNoteListner{
        fun onNoteClick(position: Int)
    }

    inner class MainHolder(itemsView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemsView){
        private val title = itemsView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fieldItem_title)
        private val body = itemsView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fieldItem_body)

        fun bind(item: Note){
            title.text = item.title
            body.text = item.body


            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                if(adapterPosition!= RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) callback.onItemClicked(items[adapterPosition])
            }
        }
    }

    interface Callback{
        fun onItemClicked(item: Note)
    }
}
```

When trying to remove a single item the error is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gCeO.png

Comment: instead of this
(mainAdapter as MainAdapter).removeItem(viewHolder,container.context)

delete item from list ( which you have pass to adapter )
and call  adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)

Comment: @KishanMaurya It doesn’t work, maybe I am not passing the element to dbHelper for deletion? I pass it like this: dbHelper.delete (mainAdapter.getItem (position).id)

Comment: var item = yourList[position]
firstly delete item from yourList,
then notify adapter then make call to DB
dbHelper.delete (item.id) 
Hope this help, else share your code, I will debug more.

Comment: Did not work out. I add code adapter and dbHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

1. remove the item from the database
2. remove the item from your adapter item list
3. call notifyItemRemoved(itemPosition) on your adapter instance

This should remove the item and also trigger a remove animation.

Comment: It did not help

Comment: How are you removing the item from your adapter item list?

Comment: (mainAdapter as MainAdapter).removeItem(viewHolder,container.context)

Comment: Well that is not how the RecyclerView works. You should remove its data not a ViewHolder. So you should remove an item from `var items: MutableList<Note>` like items.removeAt(index). After that notify the adapter that you removed an item with `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(itemPosition)`. This article seems to explain in detail how the RecyclerView works: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: Thanks, I did it.
dbHelper.deleteItem(mainAdapter.getItem(viewHolder.adapterPosition))
                listNotes.removeAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                mainAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition)

Comment: Glad to help! Keep on coding.